# Is it possible to make programs use the bpfupgradeable loader in program test crate

Tags: program-test

Hey as the title states , by default when you add programs to program test context they are added with the bpfloader and not the bpfupgradeable loader, this is an issue as i have some admin only initialize functions which i wanted to test, for the time being am using conditional compilation as a work around but would be cool if we could get a choice to select the loaders
Link : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/22950 - this seems closed

Comment: the linked github issue looks pretty open to me.  last action was me adding the `good first issue` tag

Comment: it seems there is a way to add a bpf upgradeable loader for a program ? and then test admin functons, saw the recent tests : "https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/programs/bpf-loader-tests/tests/extend_program_data_ix.rs"

Comment: Unrelated, but the Solana poc framework might have what you're looking for: https://github.com/neodyme-labs/solana-poc-framework